# How to capture click event in prototype

Tags: javascript, prototypejs, mouseclick-event

I want to prevent default link click behavior. I want that it should not redirect to that link but just show the link in alert box. I have tried this [here](http://jsfiddle.net/JeCMU/2/).

```
document.on('click', 'a.AjaxLink', function(event, element) {
    alert(element.href);
    return false;
});
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

this should work

```
document.on('click', 'a.AjaxLink', function(event, element) {
    event.stop();
    alert(element.href);
});
```